Spring RestClient - get next pages using pagination Link header
I wonder how I can idiomatically (by using built-in mechanisms in Spring) go through the next pages that are located Link header.
Right now, I need to extract it manually:
    private fun getNextPageIfExists(link: String): String? =
        if (link.contains(""">;rel="next",""")) {
            link
                .substringBefore(""">;rel="next",""")
                .substringAfterLast("<")
        } else {
            null
        }

and call RestClient with the extracted URI.

I do not not know any Java/Kotlin library that handles Link header.
I could make few suggestions to improve the final solution.
If you are ok with regular expressions, then you could use regexExtractNext.
I used kotlin.text.Regex instead of java.util.regex.Pattern in order to have more Kotlin solution.
If you want to avoid regular expressions, then you could use extractNext or extractNextV2 instead of regexExtractNext.
I would suggest to have case-insensitive solution because GitHub API, for instance, returns rel="Next".
extractNextV2 and regexExtractNext handles case-sensitivity properly.
But extractNext lowercases link before parsing. It should not be a problem, usually URIs are case-insensitive. Just keep this transformation in mind.
Regarding ;rel="next": I would suggest not assuming there is no space after ;, as GitHub API, for instance, returns ; rel="Next".
An additional benefit of extractNextV2 is that it can be easily changed to provide links for prev, last, or first simultaneously.
fun <T> processAllPages(
    firstUri: URI,
    getResponse: (URI) -> ResponseEntity<T>,
    processResponse: (ResponseEntity<T>) -> Unit
) {
    var nextPageUri: URI? = firstUri
    while (nextPageUri != null) {
        val response = getResponse(nextPageUri)
        processResponse(response)
        nextPageUri = extractNextPageUri(response)
    }
}

private fun extractNextPageUri(response: ResponseEntity<*>): URI? {
    val linkHeader = response.headers.getFirst("Link") ?: return null
    val link = regexExtractNext(linkHeader) ?: return null
    return URI(link)
}

private fun extractNextPageUri(response: ResponseEntity<*>): URI? {
    val linkHeader = response.headers.getFirst("Link") ?: return null
    val link = regexExtractNext(linkHeader) ?: return null
    return URI(link)
}

private fun regexExtractNext(linkHeader: String): String? {
    val regex = """<([^>]+)>;\s*rel="next"""".toRegex(RegexOption.IGNORE_CASE)
    return regex.find(linkHeader)?.groupValues?.getOrNull(1)
}

private fun extractNext(linkHeader: String) = linkHeader
    .lowercase() // to note
    .substringBefore("rel=\"next\"", missingDelimiterValue = "")
    .substringAfterLast('<')
    .substringBefore('>')
    .ifEmpty { null }

private fun extractNextV2(linkHeader: String): String? = linkHeader
    .split(",")
    .map { it.split(";") }
    .filter { it.size == 2 }
    .firstNotNullOfOrNull { (rawLink, rawType) ->
        val link = rawLink
            .trim()
            .trim('<', '>')
        val type = rawType
            .substringAfter("rel=")
            .trim('"')
        if (type.equals("next", ignoreCase = true)) link else null
    }

Example of usage:
@Test
fun `use on real service`() {
    val client = RestClient.create()
    processAllPages(
        firstUri = URI("https://api.github.com/user/1/repos?page=1&per_page=10"),
        getResponse = { uri -> client.get().uri(uri).retrieve().toEntity<List<Map<Any, Any>>>() },
        processResponse = { resp -> println("Repos: ${resp.body?.map { repo -> repo["id"] }}") }
    )
}

Also you could add protection against infinite loops
val processedUris = mutableSetOf<URI>()
while (nextPageUri != null && nextPageUri !in processedUris) {
    processedUris.add(nextPageUri)
    ...

Here is an example how the same problem is resolved in js https://github.com/thlorenz/parse-link-header/blob/master/index.js

is this chatgpt?

Nope, the solution is written by me)
I've even written few tests but I believe it will be verbose if I add them here

@Geba I look forward to find out if spring by itself has any support for this kind of headers

I understood you, but it was not clear from original question
I believe that Spring has no built-in mechanism to extract next from Link header
